# wso2 cep error while create a event receiver kafka type

Tags: wso2, eventreceiver, wso2-cep

It is successful to create the event receiver type `kafka` in the first time.
however the second , when I run the `kafka` again and create a new event receiver from `wso2 cep` .

It show the message as below

> "Failed to add event receiver, Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/JaasUtils"

and failed to add the new event receiver.

How should I handle that cases?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set kafka event receiver you need to configure some prerequisites. You need to [add some dependency](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Supporting+Different+Transports#SupportingDifferentTransports-KafkaTransport) jar files to set kafka event receiver. you can refer this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Kafka+Event+Receiver) for more details.